# Custom Event Listener Callback fails

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, events, listeners

I have a Flex 4.6 mobile project and I have created a custom event, I can see from various traces that the event is being dispatched as expected, but no matter what I do I cannot get a listener to work they just sit there and nothing ever happen, please take a look and tell me what could be wrong.

Custom Event:

```
package classes.events
{
import flash.events.Event; 
public class cartLoaded extends Event
{
  public static const CART_LOAD_SUCCESS:String = "cartLoadSuccess";
  public function cartLoaded(type:String, bubbles:Boolean=true, cancelable:Boolean=false)
  {
   trace("event_dispatched");
   super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
  }
  override public function clone():Event
  {
   trace("event_cloned");
   return new cartLoaded(type, bubbles, cancelable);
  }
}
}
```

The event is dispatched from a class, after a ResultEvent from a webservice call, so in the ResultEvent callback I have:

```
var cl:cartLoaded = new cartLoaded(cartLoaded.CART_LOAD_SUCCESS);
e.currentTarget.dispatchEvent(cl);
```

And I see 'event_dispatched' in the console when my results come back. So I know that the event is fired. In the parent list of the ItemRenderer that calls the class I have:

```
lst_cart.addEventListener(cartLoaded.CART_LOAD_SUCCESS,loadData);
function loadData(e:cartLoaded):void
{
    trace("set data provider");
}
```

I never see 'set data provider', now I understand that the listener must be registered before the event is dispatched, and in my case it certainly is:

Please help, as this is seriously preventing me from moving forward, I need to be able to capture this event, and I have tried everything.

As noted below, I did forget to post one part of the code, inside the class that makes the webservice call I have this line, inside the package, but outside of the class:

```
[Event(name="cartLoadSuccess", type="classes.events.cartLoaded")]
```

Which I believe you should only need if bubbles is set to false, which it was, but now it isn't.

Comment: if your event doesn't bubble than you have to register it with the element that dispatches the event, you haven't shown what lst_cart is but I assume it is a list of items, those items are dispatching your event (terrible name btw.) but ou register to listen on lst_cart try to change the event to be bubbling and see if that works.

Comment: Right, I have just tried that, and sadly it didn't work either. And when you say 'register it with the element that dispatches the event' do you mean:

    [Event(name="cartLoaded", type="claesses.events.cartLoaded")]

In the class file that dispatches the event? Inside the package, but outside the class. I hope so, because I did that too.

Shaine

Comment: lst_cart is a Spark List, that will, when I get this event to work, receive an ArrayCollection of cart items.

I assume there is a nice guide somewhere that gives guidance on naming, because apparently I need it. I already know class names should start with a capital letter, but I just didn't do that on this project, mainly because I didn't start it. It has lists as lst_, button as btn_, Images as img_ and Bitmaps as bmp_, I know people will frown on stuff that I post sometimes, but unless it affects the running of the code I post there is nothing I can do about it just yet.

Shaine

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela, I have edited the post to correctly show what is in place now. I apologize that the post was not as clear as it could have been, thank you for your assistance so far.

Comment: I have just been told this:

Classes don't fire events - instances do - and that instance must itself be attached to the display list, otherwise the event cannot bubble up the display tree.

Every instance involved in the dispatch must be attached to the display tree.

Any takers on making this correct answer, into an actual answer that I can use?

Shaine

Comment: what is `e.currentTarget` in your second code block?

Comment: I have no idea, not a clue, but it allows it to fire the event, so at this point I am not questioning it. I am led to believe from the notes that it was the only way this would work, now I do know that e.currentTarget is the ResultEvent response from the web service call.

Comment: the event meta tag is for indication that a class dispatches this particular event. In your ResultEvent could you access other parts of the program? I mean where do you need to pass this info about cart being loaded, maybe ther is no need for another event? also trace e.currentTarget and e.target please.

Comment: Right all, it appears that because the class isn't attached to the display list. The solutions offered were to have the cart class extend EventDispatcher, implement IEventDispatcher or a really odd workaround that i cant get my head round. But anyway, this isnt going to happen, as I tried to extend EventDispatcher and it failed and the other methods are just too convoluted for the scenario they will be implemented in. I think a rewrite is required.